# How to use SelectMultipleField using wtforms

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm having trouble understanding the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/) of SelectMultipleField.
it's written that

> "You’ll need to specify the HTML size attribute to the select field
> when rendering."

and I don't understand where do I specify exactly.

attached is the code (which worked) for the select field, what changes should I do for the SelectMultipleField?

**form.py**

```
domains = SelectField(label='Domain', choices=DOMAINS, validate_choice=True, validators=[InputRequired()])
```

**html**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.domains.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {% if form.domains.errors %}
            {{ form.domains(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {% for error in form.domains.errors %}
                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.domains(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'size' attribute specifies how many options of the select field you want to show in the scrollbox. For more information look at https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_size.asp

As you did, with WTF library, you can specify HTML attributes between round brackets like 'class', but many others are aviable and size is one of them, so, to fix your problem, you just need to type

```
{{ form.domains(class="form-control form-control-lg", size=x) }}
```

where x stands for the number of options you want to be visible.

Comment: This doesn't work: I did two changes: The first one as you wrote (I checked for the case of SelectField and it worked). The second one was in **form.py** I changed the code to 
`   domains = SelectMultipleField(label='Domain', choices=DOMAINS, validate_choice=True, validators=[InputRequired()])` and I got the error in the debugger: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" from this line `{{ form.domains(class="form-control form-control-lg", size="3") }}`

Comment: works for me
try size=3, not size="3"